# Javascript: How to loop through an array of objects to get a property which decreases in value by n with each iteration based on the last result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, leaflet

What I would like is for value obtained in the condition in the loop to be used in the condition in the next iteration:

```
function MakeRoute(highestEl, n) {
  let startPointsForClosest = [];

  startPointsForClosest[0] = highestEl;

  for (let i = 0; i < topographyData.length - 1; i++) {
    if (
      startPointsForClosest[i]?.topography.elevation >=
      topographyData[i]?.topography.elevation - n
    ) {
      startPointsForClosest.push(topographyData[i]);
    }
  }

  return startPointsForClosest;
}


MakeRoute({
"latlng": {
    "lat": 40.738800829681864,
    "lng": -73.7568126408477
},

"topography": {
    "elevation": 38.600000000000364,
    "slope": 1.3792065335718062,
    "aspect": 111.03751102530578,
    "resolution": 57.85092357410129
}}, n)
```

Of course on the first iteration I start the value like:

```
   startPointsForClosest[0] = highestEl;
```

However this is what I get back

This is what I got back.

```
[
    {
        "latlng": {
            "lat": 40.738800829681864,
            "lng": -73.7568126408477
        },
        "topography": {
            "elevation": 38.600000000000364,
            "slope": 1.3792065335718062,
            "aspect": 111.03751102530578,
            "resolution": 57.85092357410129
        }
    },
    {
        "latlng": {
            "lat": 40.741588319997106,
            "lng": -73.76029372856034
        },
       
        "topography": {
            "elevation": 30.700000000000728,
            "slope": 1.9044574779242354,
            "aspect": 188.9726266146405,
            "resolution": 57.84851723771878
        }
    }
]
```

Not sure why the function stops at two objects. But I should be getting at least an object with a elevation property of `36.600000000000364`?

So what i'd want is to get an array which has a collection of objects which have a decrease in elevation by n. e.g. if n was `2`:

```
[
{
    "latlng": { },
    "topography": {
        "elevation": 38.600000000000364,
        
    }
},
{
    "latlng": { },
    "topography": {
        "elevation": 36.600000000000364,
    }
},
{
    "latlng": { },
    "topography": {
        "elevation": 34,
    }
}
```

]

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/antonioOrtiz/pen/gOeEabp?editors=1112).

Comment: What is `topographyData`?  It would be easier to help you if you posted a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MattMorgan Sorry about that. I made a codepen, see update.